# C printing values of array with pointer values to a char

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

```
 typedef struct {
   char* value;
   char* type;
 } CARD;
 CARD cards[52];


 void initializeCards() { 

     char types[4][10] = {"Spade", "Club", "Hearts", "Diamonds"};
     char values[13][1] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "B", "D", "K"};

     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int e = 0; e < 13; e++) {
           cards[i*13 + e].type = types[i];
           cards[i*13 + e].value = values[e];
        }
     }

     //This prints all sorts of weid characters.
     for (int i=0; i<52; i++) {
         printf("%s %s\n", cards[i].type, cards[i].value);
     } 
 }//initializeCards.
```

I'm trying to make an array containing a deck of cards, but when I try to print the values
it prints all sorts of weird characters.

I tried using %s, %d, %c
I also tried using *cards[i].type or &cards[i].type
all without success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array `values` doesn't have enough elements to store the terminating null-character, but you are trying to print that as strings (sequences of characters terminated by a null-character) later.

Allocate enough elements so that the array can hold terminating null-characters.

Wrong line:

```
char values[13][1] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "B", "D", "K"};
```

Corrected:

```
char values[13][3] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "B", "D", "K"};
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, I have been looking at this for over an hour,  and just changing a 1 to 3, I'll accept as solved in 9minutes